# PHP xpath() undefined offset 0 but element exists // LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, xpath

i am really having trouble getting this to work. xpath works fine in other functions in the same file. I am trying to get a specific item from the XML file, which works fine when i dd() it. But when i try to load the exact same code into a variable it prompts "undefined offset 0". I am working local with Laravel.

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<idPkg:Graphic xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="15.1">
    <Color Self="Color/u2a64f" Model="Process" Space="RGB" ColorValue="204 204 204" />
</idPkg:Graphic>
```

PHP

```php
function getColor($colorID){ //$colorID = Color/u2a64f
    $xml= simplexml_load_file('/Resources/Graphic.xml');
    $colorNode = $xml->xpath('//Color[@Self="'.$colorID.'"]');

    dd($colorNode[0]->attributes()->ColorValue);

    /* outputs:
    SimpleXMLElement {#316 ▼
        +"0": "204 204 204"
    }
    */

    $fillColor = $colorNode[0]->attributes()->ColorValue; // Line of error

    /* outputs:
    ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
    Undefined offset: 0
    */

    return $fillColor;
}
```

EDIT:
what i just found out: when i replace the variable in xpath with the content of the variable it works.

```php
function getColor($colorID){ //$colorID = Color/u2a64f
    $xml= simplexml_load_file('/Resources/Graphic.xml');
    // doesnt work
    $path = '//Color[@Self="'.$colorID.'"]';

    // does work
    $path = '//Color[@Self="Color/u2a64f"]';

    $colorNode = $xml->xpath($path);

    dd($colorNode[0]->attributes()->ColorValue);

    /* outputs:
    SimpleXMLElement {#316 ▼
        +"0": "204 204 204"
    }
    */

    $fillColor = $colorNode[0]->attributes()->ColorValue; // Line of error

    /* outputs:
    ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
    Undefined offset: 0
    */

    return $fillColor;
}
```

i just cant get my head around it... I am glad for any hints or help!

Comment: Not the error, but you set `$fillColor` and return `$this->fillColor`

Comment: thx, was a copy&paste error. i edited the sourcecode!

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind i found the solution myself.

After checking my code again i saw that sometimes some XML nodes dont have the attribute FillColor. So i checked my param first if it is set and then proceed to xpath.